# Finding max, min, mode

Tags: c++

Could you review my code for finding max, min, and mode?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector <int> v = { 2, 5, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3 , 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1};
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    int number = v[0];
    int max = v[0];
    int min = v[0];
    int mode;
    for (int i = 1, countMode = 1, count = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if (v[i] == number)
            ++countMode;
        if (countMode > count) {
            count = countMode;
            mode = number;
        }
        if (v[i] > max)
            max = v[i];
        if (v[i] < min)
            min = v[i];
        number = v[i];
    }
    std::cout << max << ' ' << min << ' ' << mode;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Use direct initialization

In the first line, we have this:

```
std::vector <int> v = { 2, // ...
```

However, this may be shortened slightly by simply omitting the `=`:

```
std::vector <int> v{ 2, // ...
```

This is [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) which was standardized in C++11.

### Use "range-for" to simplify the loop

Instead of using this somewhat complicated `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 1, countMode = 1, count = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
```

You could instead use a range-for:

```
for (const auto n : v) {
```

### Avoid doing needless calculations

By definition, in a sorted list the first number will be `min` and the last `max`, so there's not much point in making those calculations.

### Use better naming

Variables `min` and `max` are good because they give a good clue as to what they hold.  However, `number` might be better called `prev` since it's the previous number in the sorted list.

Here's one way to do all of that:

```
int max = v.back();
int min = v.front();
int prev = max;
int mode;
int maxcount = 0;
int currcount = 0;
for (const auto n : v) {
    if (n == prev) {
        ++currcount;
        if (currcount > maxcount) {
            maxcount = currcount;
            mode = n;
        }
    } else {
        currcount = 1;
    }
    prev = n;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code is wrong, since you never set `countMode` to `0` when `number` changes. Furthermore, finding the minimum and maximum of an ordered vector is \$ \mathcal O(1)\$:

```
const auto min = v.front();
const auto max = v.back();
```

For the `mode`, you need to reset `countMode`:

```
for (int i = 1, countMode = 0, count = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    if (v[i] == number) {
        // we're still using the same number
        ++countMode;
    } else {
        if (countMode > count) {
           count = countMode;
           mode = number;
        }
        countMode = 1;
        number = v[i];
    }
}
// some code missing
```

Note that you need to take care of the last group of numbers. Even better, traverse the vector group-wise:

```
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
   const auto number = v[i];
   const auto start  = i;

   while(v[i] == number && i < v.size())
       ++i;

   const auto countMode = i - start;

   if(coundMode > count){
       mode = number;
       countMode = count;
   }
}
```

Other than that, your code fine. However, I would probably create a function that handles this instead, e.g.

```
template <class T>
stats<T> statistics(std::vector<T> values);
```

but that's probably an overkill.

Comment: Why would I need to initialize countMode and count to zero?

Comment: You need to reset `countMode` whenever `number` changes. Whether you reset it to `0` or `1` depends on your other logic.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
```

In smaller programs like yours, traversing a list of 3 `#include`s isn't an issue.  In larger programs, the list of `#include`d libraries can become large.  Organizing your `#include`s into logical groups and alphabetizing those subgroups helps determine if something is `#include`d.  Think about how you search a phone book.  You typically use some pivoted search to narrow down your search range.  The same applies when looking at a list of library `#include`s.

---

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Unless your intent is to invoke argument dependent lookup (ADL), I would suggest you qualify your calls.  As the reader, I'm left to try to figure out if this is a call to `std::sort` or your own rolled `sort`.  ADL can also result in [an unintended function being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712076/how-to-use-an-iterator).

If your intent was to use ADL, be explicit with a `using`-declaration.

```
using std::swap; // Explicit: opting into ADL.
swap(lhs, rhs);  // unqualified lookup, find the best match.
```

---

```
for (int i = 1, countMode = 1, count = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    if (v[i] == number)
        ++countMode;
    if (countMode > count) {
        count = countMode;
        mode = number;
    }
}
```

It should be noted that the calculation for the `mode` is incorrect.  You never reset the `countMode` value, so your function returns the last duplicate value seen rather than the `mode`.

Assuming you fix that, consider other possible sequence structures.

- Many duplicates - where `mode([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])` should result in the multimodal set `[1, 2, 3]`.
- Unique values - where `mode([1, 2, 3])` should result in the empty set `[]`.
- Empty set - where `mode([])` should result in the empty set `[]`.

Consider how your program handles these situations.

In the case of an empty set, `v[0]` doesn't exist.  Attempting to access `v[0]` produces a segmentation fault.  `mode` is also never initialized and your program will exhibit undefined behavior if you try to do anything with that value.

---

While it is easy for beginner's to just dump everything into `main()`, I would suggest you break your program up into smaller, focused, and testable logical abstractions.  `min` and `max` elements are as simple as calls to `front()` and `back()` on sorted lists.  If you want those values for unsorted lists, the standard library provides `std::min_element`, `std::max_element` and `std::minmax_element` in the `<algorithm>` library.  `mode` should be abstracted into it's own function as well utilizing other abstractions to accomplish its task.